# What does [](){} construction mean in c++?

Tags: c++, boost, syntax, foreach

I have this code.

```
boost::for_each(
    boost::make_iterator_range(
            func(arg1),
            func(arg2)
        ),
        [&d, &f](const a<b>& c)
        {
            something;
        }
);
```

I understand the iterator part of the code. What is not clear to me is over what we iterate. What does this construction mean? `[](){}`

Comment: [This question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7627098/what-is-a-lambda-expression-in-c11) has a pretty good explanation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a `lambda-expression` , an anonymous method/function. You can provide it inline if there is no reason to define a distinct function.
`[]` binds the local parameters either by value `[]` or by reference `[&]`. In `()` you pass your values like in a function call and `{}` embraces the function body.

See [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/c++11/c++11-lambda-closures.html).