# What does this do in C++? []() {}()

Tags: c++

I am unit testing for code coverage, making sure that every possible code path is executed by a unit test.

I find that a switch/case element which merely contains a break can be breakpointed, but that the break is never hit, control just jumps to the end of the switch, presumably because of compiler optimization.

A colleague is arguing that that I have not adequately unit test that path.

So, I searched and found an S.O question - which I can not longer find - about C++ code that does nothing. The only answer that didn't also get optimized away of generate compiler or static code analysis errors was `[]() {}()`.

This works, insomuch as a breakpoint on it will be hit.

Problem solved, I guess, but what does that actually do?

Comment: `[](){}` is a do nothing lambda function. And the extra `()` calls that function. Not sure why that could not be optimised away however.

Comment: [What does `[](){}` construction mean in c++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15389579/995714), [How is `int main(){(([](){})());}` valid C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/13603286/995714), [What is a lambda expression in C++11?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7627098/995714)

Comment: For your colleague, you could replace it with `<::>()<%%>();` which has the advantage of looking more bug-like.

Comment: Lol! I like the look of that, but won't pretend that I understand it :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is an empty lambda that gets executed and does nothing. Usually to set a breakpoint in debugging, at the end of a function or another code block.

```
[] () {   } ()
^^^ ------------------- no captures
   ^^^ ---------------- no parameters
        ^^^------------ function body
             ^^ ------- call operator (operator()) with no arguments.
```

Compare this with a Lambda that actually does something:

```
int x = 5;
auto lambda = [&x](int i){ x=x*i; };
lambda(2);
std::cout << "x is now: " << x << "\n"; // prints x=10
```

If a function gets optimised out or not is compiler specific.

[I composed a small example on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/z/1efKj56aq)

```
#include <iostream>

inline void nothing(){}

int main(){
    int x = 5;
    [](){}();
    nothing();
    std::cout << x+3 << "\n";
}
```

Depending on the optimisation `-O0` or `-O1`, ... and if the `nothing()` function is marked inline or not, you can see a difference in the assembly.

In gcc12.1 and `-O1` the empty lambda is optimised out as well as the call to `nothing()`. If you remove the `inline` keyword, even the `nothing()` declaration disappears as well

Comment: Ah, thanks for clarifying. So, that code is, in effect, an infinite zer0?